# Difference between "submittal by" and "submitted by"

Tags: word-choice

On a sample plan of study, I see the word submittal by.
I don't see this word much, and I don't get much information from the dictionary.

What is the difference between *submittal by* and *submitted by*?

**Context**

> 2011 Chinese Government Scholarship for International Students
>
> at University of International Business and Economic
>
> A PROPOSAL FOR MY PLAN OF STUDY
>
> Submittal by
>
> Firstname Lastname

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing it in context but "Submittal by" may be looking for a date when you plan on submitting your finished paper/project.  Whereas "submitted by" is looking for the name of the person submitting the plan.

Comment: Yes, more context, please!  Why only give us two words?  Why not share the whole sentence from the study plan?

Comment: sorry. it is in the header of study plan, context added

Comment: One tells us who wrote it, the other tells us who submitted it. Since those would usually be the same person, it typically makes no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either word (*submittal* or *submitted*) could work.

If you wrote:

> *proposal submitted by Sarawut Positwinyu*

that would mean that Sarawut submitted the proposal.  The *proposal* would the subject, *submitted* is the transitive verb, and Sarawut Positwinyu is the object. (Using *submitted* as a [transitive verb](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/intransitiveverb.htm) here requires the proposal to be submitted *by* someone, or *to* someone, such as a committee, or *for* some reason.)

If you instead wrote:

> *submittal by Sarawut Positwinyu*

submittal is a noun (meaning, *that which has been submitted*), and the prepositional phrase merely qualifies who submitted the proposal.

As for getting some guidance from the dictionary, check out [this entry from **Collins**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/submittal).  You can see *submittal* listed as a noun, and *submit* listed as a verb.  In your example, *submit* would be used as a verb under Meaning #3, *to refer something for judgment or consideration*.

As Roaring Fish indicated, *submitted* could also be used as an adjective, as in:

> The committee reviewed the submitted report.

Answer (score 0):

[Submittal](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/192832?redirectedFrom=submittal#eid) is a noun, while [submitted](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/192834?redirectedFrom=submitted#eid) can be used as an adjective or verb.

They can both convey the same information, but the sentence construction would be different:

- "This is the submitted work by David" (*adj*.)
- "This was a submittal by David" (*n*.)
- "This work was submitted by David" (*v*.)

Comment: Submitted is a verb in past tense.

Comment: "I am buried by submitted homework"?  But yeah... not a good example, and it doesn't even have 'by' in it. I'll change it.

Comment: *Submitted* can indeed be used as an adjective, but, when followed by *by*, it's probably a past tense verb.  You need to give three examples, not two.

Comment: I am giving up on this one. The question keeps changing.